# Is Halide indexing row major, column major, or a mix?

Tags: halide

I would like to check my understanding of how indexing in Halide works.

In many tutorials I see halide buffers indexed as [x,y,c], namely [column, row, channel]. The function that triggers JIT is consistent with this:

```
realize(input.width(), input.height(), input.channels())
```

How is the underlying data stored?

My impression from the documentation and reading tutorials is that the data is still stored in row-major [height, width, channels] order, but their DSL swaps the first two indeces. So the indexing isn't row major or column major, but something in between with strides that aren't strictly increasing or decreasing.

If this is really correct, how does it extend to four dimensions? Is the rule that indexing is row major, except that you always swap the first two indeces?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Halide stores the leftmost dimension innermost. So if you have a 2D image

```
Func f;
f(x, y) = ...;
```

Then the data layout is stored in row major order, since `y` is the outermost dimension. This can be changed in the schedule to be column major via:

```
f.reorder_storage(y, x);
```

For 3D images where you have `f(x, y, c)`, the color channels are outermost, making it a planar image. This is also how iteration works: `x` is the innermost loop by default.

When dealing with input images, you will have to set the strides manually. For instance, if you want to input an interlaced image, and `f` were an input, then you would write:

```
f.dim(0).set_stride(3)  // x -- RGB, 4 for RGBA
 .dim(2).set_stride(1); // c -- stride for channels is 1.
                        // stride for y will be 3 * width
```

See more about memory layout at:
https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_16_rgb_generate.html